# EF Core 3.1 Update Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I want to update my entity using EF Core. Which one of these 2 approaches is more efficient and better to use.

```
Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified
Context.SaveChanges();
```

and the next one is

```
var exist = entities.Find(entity.Id);
Context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);  
Context.SaveChanges();
```

both of theme do the job but which one is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your situation. First one, as far as I understand should rewrite whole entity in db. Second one can possibly make an [extra request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-3.1) to the database if entity is not already tracked by context, but should update only fields which [actually have changed](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/08/updating-entity-framework-objects.aspx). So if you have change tracking enabled and already fetched the entity into your context, and have a lot of columns (or columns which contain a lot of data and can be compared by EF) second one should be faster. In other cases - first one could.